# Alter response in PostMan

Tags: postman

I'm using an open API.

But I am only using a small bit of data from the response the API provides. And as I'm testing using the API with different parameters to see the responses.

I don't want to see the entire API response every time I send the request, I only want to see the data that I'm interested in.

**For example :**

The response has 3 objects. `Status`, `Features` and `Data`. But I'm only interested in the `Data` object, I only want to see the `Data` object when making the request

Is there a way I can print a different Response, using the actual response of the Request?

Tests are run to validate data, and Pre-Request scripts are used to do something before the request, but I haven't found anything that changes the form of the Response.

Comment: hi what you mean by form of response , could you add an example

Comment: @PDHide I edited the question, hope it's clear now

Comment: What you mean by print console.log( ) or in the postman ui . In script you can print anything you want and view it in console . But in the response session of ui yiu cannot do that

Comment: In the response view. Since there I can close and search, while in Log I can't view it formatted

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no option to modify body but you can use the amazing visualizer feature in postman:

**eg:**

**Set url and method:**

```
    GET :  https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
```

**Add below code in test script:**

```
template = `<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>

        {{#each response}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{email}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`
    response: pm.response.json().data
});
```

**Now click visualize:**

[image]

You can see the visualize will show only first_name and email as a table .

You can use same logic in your case

**If you want to print it as json itself then use below code in test script:**

```
template = `
<pre><code>{{response}}</code></pre>
`;

console.log( JSON.stringify(pm.response.json().data, undefined, 2))
// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`
    response: JSON.stringify(pm.response.json().data, undefined, 2)
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's actually quite nice, I can actually see the response in a table, instead of just raw data. But I don't think I'm getting it to work? I copied the json template one, without the log, it still shows an empty text. Is `response` a variable, or does it take it automatically?

Comment: Also, i don't see a let or var in your code, didn't think JS had those implicate?

Comment: @AhmadSattout just use the url as mentioned in the example , and copy the code as it is . Understand how it works and then try with your endpoint and modify the code according to your context

Comment: Let or var declaration is not required when you do assign Operation ..but it's a good practice to use let (than var )

Comment: Thanks, that's a realy nice feature