# Rest API - Pulling and filtering data

Tags: javascript, api, csv, postman, rest

I'm trying to pull some data using api call. My export should contain only 3 columns - "title", "header", "body".

My post request in Postman:

```
  {
    "format": "csv",
    "date": "2021-03-02",
    "columns": [
    {
      "column_id": "title"
    },
    {
      "column_id": "header"
    },
{
      "column_id": "body"
    }
  ]}
```

After making a post requests like that, I get :

```
starter_id, date, title, header, body, body_inn
001, 2021-03-02, Scrapper, fulOsc, MF, MF_121
002, 2021-03-02, PogoScrapper, fulPsc, GF, GF_1HG
003, 2021-03-02, MonoScrapper, fulBsc, HF, HF_CF
```

I get additionally starter_id, date and body_inn. I don't want any of them in my data, what can I do to get only thos 3 which I want from the start, without any default/additional columns?

Comment: REST unlike Graphql, is static in terms of what resources it serves. I'm assuming you do not control the API code and it also doesn't columns parameter. You could contact or check the documention if any to if this is possible. Otherwise you will have to create an array map function remove the unwanted columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alter response in PostMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554111/alter-response-in-postman)

Answer (score 0):

The variable named `mapped` is going to have what you want

```
let mapped = results
    .map(result => ({"title" : result.title,
                   "header" : result.header,
                   "body" : result.body}));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it in my case? I pasted it to Tests in Postman but it's not working...

Comment: I don't think postman enables you to use Java Script. You should do this in your front end app, if you have one, or in your backend API before returning the results to the requesting party. `results` is what you are getting now and `mapped` is what you want.